# Empty HTTP POST request or GET request to generate a random value through an HTTP API

Tags: http, rest, web, asp.net-web-api

In my HTTP API, one of the endpoints should return an randomly generated value and that value will be associated with the authenticated caller of the endpoint. Currently, I have the following structure:

```
GET http://example.com/random-ticket HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic base64-encoded-basic-auth-value
Accept: application/json
Host: example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 07:25:56 GMT
Content-Length: 59

{"user-ticket":"Pfa42634e-1a2e-4a7d-84b9-2d5c46a8dd81"}
```

A GET request is issued to retrieve the random value. However, [HTTP GET calls should be idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Examples) and my above implementation is not obeying that rule. On the other hand, **I'm not sure if it's OK to issue HTTP POST requests with an empty message body.**

What is the right way of performing this type of operations by the HTTP book?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Safe => whether call results in a change of state on the server.
- Idempotent => whether multiple calls result in the same change on the server.

So the question is not the data that is returned. Rather it is the server state: so if <s>you are storing this value on the server</s> this results in a change in the state, then it is not fit for GET. Otherwise if it is the data that is returned, it is fine. Call to http://stackoverflow.com returns different data if called 10 minutes apart.

Let's look at another example, a **Clock service** which returns the current time. Everytime you make the call, you get a different value but the call itself does not result in a change in the state on the server since the clock state is maintained separately. So using GET here is a good choice.

Comment: creating a resource != storing value on the server

Comment: @FilipW I did not say storing a value. It is **changing state**.

Comment: thanks guys. This answer is more descriptive and removed all my confusions.

Comment: you said "if you are storing this value on the server, then it is not fit for GET."

Answer (score 12):

There is absolutely nothing in the HTTP prohibiting the use of POST with an empty body.

Moreover, message carries a representation, which is body + headers. In your case body is 0 length, which is fine, and the headers which identify the user.

See discussion here - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2010JulSep/0273.html

Comment: Sorry, I talked about GET by confusion! But also the question is the server state which is not mentioned here and is the key.

Comment: I think the OP is quite aware that he shouldn't use GET here, so I tried to explain why he shouldn't be afraid to use POST insteadd

Comment: Me neither. GET is completely ok if the random number was generated in-memory and is not part of an existing resource that would change in side effect.

Comment: We are not talking about creating a value that has no relationship to server state. From what I understand, the generated ticket will be associated with the user, so effectively a new resource has been created (a "user-ticket" resource).

That's why I don't believe a clock service is a good analogy too.

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem having a random generator with a GET as there is no server state that is being stored. In the same way you could have a calculator that accepts params and adds them when a GET is called. The question about cachable is an interesting one, though doesn't really apply to a random generator as the resource by nature is not cached. That still doesn't change the fact that it can be designed in a safe/idempotent fashion.

As to POST without a body, or even using params in a query string, that is fine. The key thing about POST is that it 'may' result in a change to the server. It's not guaranteed either that it will, but you can't assume it won't as with a GET. Whether or not there is any content being set, doesn't change the fact that there can be a change. For example imagine a fictitious resource "\counter\increment". Each time you POST to it it will cause \counter to increment. I haven't sent any payload, but I am causing a change in server state thus it should be POST or PUT.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `POST` in this case because, by desgin, `GET` calls can be cached. Regarding empty post body, there is no issue. A similar scenarios is also discussed at: [POST with empty body](http://w3-org.9356.n7.nabble.com/POST-with-empty-body-td103965.html), in which one post mentions:

> a POST with no content-length and no body is equivalent to a POST with Content-Length: 0 and nothing following, as could perfectly happen when you upload an empty file for instance. The resource is determined by the URL and the server has to know how to handle the body, including if it's empty. I don't see the issue here in fact :-/
>
> Willy

Comment: "GET calls can be cached" which is correct, but depending on the data consistency you want to achieve i.e. how often data changes on the server. So you also might have GET requests you don't want to allow caching. Additionally, think of authenticated data that must not be cached either. So your caching argument does not fit here exactly.

Comment: You can return appropriate cache headers.